# Smart way to set 2 variable based on a 3rd variable values without using if

Tags: python, python-2.7, if-statement

I have a code where I pass a value in `whichweek` and then it returns the values of `dayf`and `dayt`
I am using the if statement but it's pretty long and it doesn't feel "pythonic" at all. Is there any elegant way to write this?

here is the way I do it:

```
if whichweek == 5:
    dayf = 0
    dayt = 32
elif whichweek == 1:
    dayf = 0
    dayt = 8
elif whichweek == 2:
    dayf = 7
    dayt = 15
elif whichweek == 3:
    dayf = 14
    dayt = 22
elif whichweek == 4:
    dayf = 21
    dayt = 29
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: Use a dictionary to map `whichweek` to `dayf, dayt` e.g. `mapping = {5: (0, 32), 1: (0, 8).....}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, there are few ones to make it more pythonic, I'd use a dictionary packing all the data, ie:

```
import random

if __name__ == "__main__":
    random.seed(1)

    week_data = {
        1: (0, 32),
        2: (0, 8),
        3: (7, 15),
        4: (14, 22),
        5: (21, 29)
    }

    for i in range(10):
        whichweek = random.randint(1, 5)
        dayf, dayt = week_data[whichweek]
        print whichweek, dayf, dayt
```

If you want to handle errors, you can use something like this:

```
import random

if __name__ == "__main__":
    random.seed(1)

    week_data = {
        1: (0, 32),
        2: (0, 8),
        3: (7, 15),
        4: (14, 22),
        5: (21, 29)
    }

    for i in range(10):
        whichweek = random.randint(1, 10)
        res = week_data.get(whichweek, None)

        if res is None:
            print("Error: {0} is not in week_data".format(whichweek))
        else:
            dayf, dayt = res
            print whichweek, dayf, dayt
```

Finally, if you want to avoid that conditional check, return always values like this:

```
import random

if __name__ == "__main__":
    random.seed(1)

    week_data = {
        1: (0, 32),
        2: (0, 8),
        3: (7, 15),
        4: (14, 22),
        5: (21, 29)
    }

    for i in range(10):
        whichweek = random.randint(1, 10)
        dayf, dayt = week_data.get(whichweek, (None, None))
        print whichweek, dayf, dayt
```

Comment: Your code will throw an error if whichweek isn't a key in days. Better to use days.get(whichweek) and check if None or wrap the bracket access call in a try-except block.

Answer (score 3):

```
weeks = {1: (0, 8)}
try:
    dayf = weeks[1][0]
    dayt = weeks[1][1]
except (KeyError, IndexError):
    pass
```

Comment: This is the only answer so far that actually replicates the behavior defined by OP.  Namely, `dayf` and `dayt` are not defined if whichweek is not in the dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

Create a dictionary to map the value `whichweek` as key to corresponding values of `dayf` and `dayt`. Even better to make a call to this dict using a function *(I personally love these simple and task oriented functions)*.

Below is the sample code:

```
def get_values(key):
    return {
         1: (0, 8),
         2: (7, 15),
         3: (14, 22),
         4: (21, 29)
         5: (0, 32),
     }.get(key, (None, None))

dayf, dayt = get_values(5)
# Value of 'dayf' = 0 and 'dayt' = 32 

dayf, dayt = get_values(9)
# Since '9' is not the valid key; 'dayf' = None and 'dayt' = None
```

---

In case you do not want to set any value to `dayf` and `dayt` if `whichweek` is having unknown values (*as my above solution is setting dayf and dayt as `None` in this scenario*), slightly updated version of the above code will be:

```
def get_values(key):
    return {
        1: (0, 8),
        2: (7, 15),
        3: (14, 22),
        4: (21, 29)
        5: (0, 32),
    }[key]

try:
    dayf, dayt = get_values(5)
except KeyError:
    pass
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use a dictionary:

```
days = {
    5: (0, 32),
    1: (0, 8),
    2: (7, 15),
    3: (14, 22),
    4: (21, 29)
}

dayf, dayt = days[whichweek]
```

Comment: Nice! What will happen, if `whichweek` is not in the dictionary? :)

Comment: Your code will throw an error if `whichweek` isn't a key in `days`. Better to use `days.get(whichweek)` and check if None or wrap the bracket access call in a try-except block.